# How to download a file containing ampersand?

Tags: c#, html, angular6, webclient

I am having trouble with downloading the files with filenames containing ampersand in C#. I am using HTML download attribute and there are many files which contain an ampersand in a filename. Are there any options to download files with filename containing ampersand with download attribute in HTML?

I have tried using WebClient as well as other methods for downloading the file and I need to have the file downloaded as we download a file from the internet in the browser.

```
<a href="{{items.FilePath}}{{items.FileName}}" data-toggle="tooltip" 
data-placement="top" title="{{items.FileName}}" download> </a>

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
client.DownloadFile(paths,@"c:\Users\Jon\Test\foo.txt");
}
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(string filePath, string fileName)
{
string paths = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath+ fileName);
        var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(paths);
        var fileMemStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(fileMemStream);
        var headers = result.Content.Headers;
        headers.ContentDisposition = new 
 System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
        headers.ContentType = new 
 System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet- 
  stream");
        headers.ContentLength = fileMemStream.Length;
        return result;
    }
```